# How do you composite 3D SceneKit content onto video frames on the GPU on iOS?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, scenekit, core-video

I am working on an AR app. I have a SceneKit scene being rendered into a SCNView (using OpenGL ES as the rendering API). Beneath this is another view showing a live preview of the camera. I would like to create a movie containing both the video and the 3D scene.

I am using code based on Apple’s RosyWriter sample code to process the video frame pixel buffers with OpenGL shaders. I don’t think I’ve quite understand the concepts well enough because I’m not sure how to overlay the SceneKit rendering on the video frames. Can I get a pixel buffer from the SCNView/SCNSceneRenderer or do I need to use an SCNRenderer to re-render the scene to a texture in the offscreen buffer that the OpenGL capture pipeline uses to process video frames?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In iOS 11, there's now a technology for easily doing not just SceneKit overlays on video, but a whole augmented reality experience: [ARKit](https://developer.apple.com/arkit). (Also, if you're rolling your own AR tracking tech bit want to display using SceneKit, in iOS 11 you can set an `AVCaptureDevice` as the contents of any SceneKit material property, including a scene's background.)

For older iOS versions, the below advice still applies...

---

If you already have content that you're rendering using OpenGL (or Metal, for that matter), and you want to add SceneKit content to it, use `SCNRenderer`. Set a scene on it just like you would with `SCNView`, do all your existing OpenGL rendering the way you usually do, and then call `renderAtTime:`.

Just for a proof of concept, here's a *really quick hack* at adding SceneKit rendering on top of [RosyWriter](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/RosyWriter/). All the code below goes into `RosyWriterOpenGLRenderer.m`.

In the declaration of instance variables:

```
@interface RosyWriterOpenGLRenderer ()
{
    //... existing ivars, plus:
    SCNRenderer *_scnRenderer;
}
```

In `init`, after setting up `_oglContext`:

```
_scnRenderer = [SCNRenderer rendererWithContext:_oglContext options:nil];
SCNScene *scene = [SCNScene scene];
SCNNode *node = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:[SCNBox geometry]];
[node runAction:[SCNAction repeatActionForever:[SCNAction rotateByX:1 y:1 z:1 duration:1]]];
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:node];
_scnRenderer.scene = scene;
```

In `copyRenderedPixelBuffer`, between the existing call to `glFlush()` and the `bail` label:

```
glFlush();

[_scnRenderer renderAtTime:CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()];

bail:
```

That's enough to get a big spinning white cube both in the live video view and in the recorded movie output. (It's only unshaded because of the default material and lighting setups. For a real use case, set up lights, materials, cameras, the geometry you want, etc.)

[image: no, my desk isn't really that pink.]